# Mapbox-GL why not using AGG for map rendeing?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, mapbox, mapbox-gl

- [AGG (Anti-Grain Geometry)](http://www.antigrain.com/) is a High Quality Rendering Engine for C++.
- [OpenGL ES](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/) is a royalty-free, cross-platform API for full-function 2D and 3D graphics on embedded systems.

But AGG seems more efficient than OpenGL ES in map rendeing, like [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org) is using AGG.

**Q1:**  [Mapbox-GL](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native) why not use AGG but use OpenGL?

**Q2:**  What's the difference between AGG and OpenGL ES?

Thanks! **:)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re Q1 and Q2:

OpenGL/-ES is usually GPU accelerated (in fact on most platforms with OpenGL-ES support, OpenGL-ES is available only if a GPU is present). AGG is a software rasterizer.

Thus if a GPU is present it's usually more efficient/performant to use OpenGL/-ES if the intention to generate output for an interactive (realtime) display.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is an API for managing buffers on a GPU and specifying functions to map data between them; having originally been for the rendering of 3d geometry it's still primarily oriented around that goal. It's an open standard with 25 years of history that is implemented by all of the major vendors on all of the major operating systems and a subset of which is now even incorporated into standards-compliant web browsers.

Anti-Grain Geometry is a CPU-based 2d rasterisation library from a single vendor that appears to have started somewhere around 2001 and hasn't seen any web page updates since 2007. The most recent post to its mailing list is about its fractured state due to various independent downstream patches.

A developer might prefer AGG to OpenGL because the latter is very low level and not especially developer friendly. It provides very little unless you put the effort in and debugging tools are often poor. The former appears to be a high-level library which, since it operates on the CPU, will be amenable to your normal debugger.

However, AGG isn't accelerated, has no clear ownership or future, has no forum for governorship and isn't widely available.